# investment word problem

Tags: word-problem

I cannot figure out how to set up the following word problem into an equation.

Raoul invested \$40,000 in 2  different types of bonds. The first type earned 4% and the second type earned 5%. If the profit (interest) on the 5% bonds was $200 more than the profit (interest) on the 4% bonds, how much did Raoul invest in the 5% bonds?

This is what I have so far:

x= how much Raoul invested in the 5% bond.
50,000 - x = how much Raoul invested in the 4% bond.

But how can I us the $200 more profit earned if I don't know the amount of profit in the first place?

Comment: It looks like 40,000 in the second paragraph became 50,000 in the fourth.

Comment: What is the capital $\$40,000$ or $\$50,000$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
The statement

> the profit (interest) on the $5\%$ bonds was $\$200$ more than the profit (interest) on the $4\%$ bonds

put in algebraic terms gives the equation

\begin{align*}
0.05x&=0.04(40,000-x)+200
\end{align*}

Comment: @j3238254 Therefore Raoul invested $\$50,000$ ?

Comment: @callculus: According to the statement must be $\$40,000$. I hope the OP pay attention at this point. Thanks.